# Set content type in restangular for put request globally

Tags: node.js, angularjs, restangular

I am using nodejs server and [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)(angular framework) to build a RESTfull API.

When I make a POST request, the form data is sent in request payload(body).

But when I make a PUT request, the form data is appended to the URL as a query string.

How can I configure restangular to send form data inside body similar to POST request?

Comment: what's wrong with like Restangular.one('user',id).put() I can see the same as post

Comment: @Whisher the difference can be seen when Restangular.one('user',id).put(userinfo) and Restangular.one('user',id).post(userinfo) are compared.

Comment: the put method don't have data as parameters its  Restangular.one('user',id).put() not Restangular.one('user',id).put(userinfo) sorry but what's for  Restangular.one('user',id).post(userinfo) usually I do  Restangular.all('user').post(data) for create or Restangular.one('user', id).put() for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use customPUT() instead of put().

```
baseObj.customPUT(newObj).then(callbackFunction);
```

Comment: By the way it has nothing to do with setting content type.